# Access from Thymeleaf to class field

Tags: java, thymeleaf

How to access from Thymeleaf to some simple POJO static property ? For example:

```
public final static int PROJECT_NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 255;
```

how to type:

```
<input type="text" th:maxlength="??" />
```

Comment: Are you using Spring as well?

Comment: yes, Spring 4.0.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since you are using Spring, thymeleaf has access to the EL provided by Spring. You should therefore be able to use

```
<input type="text" th:maxlength="${T(com.example.MyType).PROJECT_NAME_MAX_LENGTH}" />
```