# SpringBoot Thymeleaf ordinal numbers

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, datetime-format

I have read a few good posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4011075/1756598) which explain the method of receiving ordinal numbers when given an `int`.

Now, I have a LocalDate object and I can format my dates using any of the `DateTimeFormat` patterns in my Thymeleaf template. Example being something like:

```
<strong th:text="${item.date} ? ${#temporals.format(item.date, 'dd')}"></strong>
```

**Question:** How can I or perhaps what is the best way of achieving similar results to the [post I linked to above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4011075/1756598) in Thymeleaf.

I am not an experienced Java developer so it would be very helpful if you be as thorough as you possibly can with explaining the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the Thymeleaf's template you can [use static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120799/access-from-thymeleaf-to-class-field) (and functions), so in you case it will looks like that:
1) [Code from the question you related (I just modified it a little bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java) :

```
package your.packagename;
// http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.*;

public class YourClass {

    public static String getDayOfMonthSuffix(String num) {
        Integer n = Integer.valueOf(num == null ? "1" : num);
        checkArgument(n >= 1 && n <= 31, "illegal day of month: " + n);
        if (n >= 11 && n <= 13) {
            return "th";
        }
        switch (n % 10) {
            case 1:  return "st";
            case 2:  return "nd";
            case 3:  return "rd";
            default: return "th";
        }
    }
}
```

2) Call it inside the view :

```
<strong th:text="${#temporals.format(item.date, 'dd') + T(your.packagename.YourClass).getDayOfMonthSuffix(#temporals.format(item.date, 'dd'))}"></strong>
```