# Cannot access web context objects with thymeleaf in Spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

From looking at the thymeleaf [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-a-expression-basic-objects), I've tried to access web context objects with thymeleaf in my Spring boot project in this manner:

```
<p th:text="${#request.getRequestURL()}">lol</p>
```

which results in the following exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: 
Attempted to call method getRequestURL() on null context object
```

From this error it seems that I might be missing a dependency? I've seen  a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157364/error-attempted-to-call-method-format-on-null-context-object), where the solution was to add an `extras` thymeleaf package as a dependency.

However, it is stated in the thymeleaf documentation that these *objects and variable maps are always available to be invoked* so I guess that shouldn't be the case here.

I'm using the release 1.5.1 of `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` as well as a number of other `spring-boot-starter` packages like `web` and `security`.

Comment: just tried and it is working fine by using `thymeleaf  3.0.2.RELEASE`, `thymeleaf-layout-dialect 2.1.1` and `spring boot 1.4.3.RELEASE`. No extra module needed.

Comment: You're right. Found out that a minimum of `thymeleaf-spring4:3.0.0.RELEASE` and `thymeleaf-layout-dialect 2.0.0` are required to access web context objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with `thymeleaf-spring4:3.0.0.RELEASE` and `thymeleaf-layout-dialect 2.0.0`, so seems like these are the minimum versions required.

The `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.5.1.RELEASE` only provides `thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.5.RELEASE` and `thymeleaf-layout-dialect 1.4.0`.