# Access from Thymeleaf to constants (without spring)

Tags: java, thymeleaf

How to access from Thymeleaf to constant?

```
public final static int SOME_CONSTANT = 255;
```

I am using the following code:

```
@com.company.project.classWithConstants@SOME_CONSTANT
```

And I am getting the following exception:

> com/company/project/classWithConstants (wrong name:  com/company/project/ClassWithConstants)

(There is a similar question at SO, but OP is using spring: [Access from Thymeleaf to class field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120799/access-from-thymeleaf-to-class-field))

Comment: Might be a typo? Try com.company.project.ClassWithConstants. If it doesn't work, can you try renaming your constant to someConstant and adding a getter with the name getSomeConstant and see if what you are using works? Might help getting an answer, and also for science :)

Comment: @Jorge.V ClassWithConstants works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, Thymeleaf uses **OGNL** to process commands.
So, Without Spring and SpEL this can be achieved like this:

```
<td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="inputValue"
        th:maxlength="${@com.example.yourpackagename.Constants@MAX_TESTCASE_VALUE_LENGTH}" />
</td>
```

[**OGNL documentation**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html)